# how to align one item in the OL to the right while the others are on the left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using the breadcrumb class of Bootstrap in the OL element. Aside from the breadcrumb info, I want to add a last update info to the right of the OL. I used the text-align:right but it didn't work. Is it possible? thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
"<ol class='breadcrumb'>" +
"<li>2015</li>" + 
"<li>Feb Release</li>" +
"<li style:'text-align:right'>Last Update: 3:15pm</li>" +
"</ol>";
```

Comment: Typo: change `style:'text-align:right'` to `style='text-align:right'` - example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/BNbBKv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Bootstrap's `pull-right` class...

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li>2015</li>
<li>Feb Release</li>
<li class="pull-right">Last Update: 3:15pm</li>
</ol>
```

http://codeply.com/go/jb4uBgIIX1